# Es Upgrade error "Plugin [repository-url] was built for Elasticsearch version 6.5.4 but version 7.6.0 is running"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have upgraded my Elasticsearch version from `6.5.4` to `7.6.0`, and when I am trying to start my ES I am getting an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin [repository-url] was built for Elasticsearch version 6.5.4 but version 7.6.0 is running
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.verifyCompatibility(PluginsService.java:346) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:531) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:471) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:313) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I resolve this error.

Comment: When you do a major version upgrade you have to assume that the plugin API may have changed.  Any and all plugins you have need to be tested with your new configuration--and very likely you need a new version.  In this case you definitely do.

Comment: Try `sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin remove repository-url` to remove the plugin and then re-install it.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch tried the command but then I am getting `could not find java in bundled jdk at /opt/bitnami/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java`

Comment: You'll have to trace that down.  I don't know how you installed Elastic 7.6.  If the bundled JDK is in a different location, you may need to add a symlink to the new location.  If `elasticsearch-plugin` is a script, you may be able to edit it to use whatever version of Java you have.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I have changed java version but now when I am trying to remove the package I am getting error `ERROR: plugin [repository-url] not found; run 'elasticsearch-plugin list' to get list of installed plugins`, can you please tell me how can I resolve it, I have tried everything but nothing is working for me.